# Github page not linking to CSS

Tags: css, github

I'm working on HTML/CSS page. Here is my [repo](https://github.com/jessc003/google-homepage). The [page](https://jessc003.github.io/google-homepage/) won't load the CSS file when referenced like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Google Homepage</title>
</head>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Laif no, no raw link needed.

Comment: try this `./style.css`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: your css is working properly. but you don't know css and wrote wrong.`footer` and `.footer` not same. look at the body from google console and see that css is implemented properly.

Comment: your css is working fine..!

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct path to the sheet file: href=".\style.css"